# Controller action not being hit

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have the following form that is trying to let a User SignIn:

```asp
<form method="post" asp-controller="Auth" asp-action="SignIn">
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col">
            <input class="form-control" type="email" placeholder="Email" id="email-input" name="email">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col">
            <input class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Password" id="password-input" name="password">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col">
            <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="button" style="width: 100%;">Login</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

As you can see the form is using a Controller named Auth and an action on the Controller named SignIn. Here is a sample of the Controller:

```
public class AuthController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new SignInViewModel());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> SignIn(SignInViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (await _userService.ValidateCredentials(model.Email, model.Password, out var user))
            {
                await SignInUser(user.Email);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
        }
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

I've set a breakpoint on the line `if (ModelState.IsValid)` and it never gets hit. When I click the login button the page simply refreshes. I really cannot see why this breakpoint is not being hit when the Controller and the Action seem OK to me.

EDIT: `SignInViewModel`:

```
public class SignInViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter an Email Address")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter a Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Snippet from Chrome:

[image]

Comment: Try inspecting the generated html in your browser to check if the action is right

Comment: @Phiter Do you have a guide on how I can do that?

Comment: On any browser, right click on your page and go to "Inspect Element". You'll see a html markup on a panel. Look for the form and check if it has the `action` attribute

Comment: Shouldn't asp-controller="Auth" be asp-controller="AuthController "?

Comment: SignInViewModel model - this is a source of problem. Your form cannot be parsed as SignInViewModel, possibly missed or redudant variables?

Comment: @Damon, in asp.net you don't need to include "Controller" on the references. It adds "Controller" to the class to specify it's purpose, but understands that this part isn't necessary when calling them.

Comment: @Dmitriy: How are you certain?  Are you seeing code we're not seeing?  Wouldn't an unconstructable model still reach the action but simply with a `null` model?

Comment: @Phiter it looks like `action: ""` so assume that is the problem. Not sure I understand that though when it looks like it is setup correctly?

Comment: For some reason, aspnet isn't generating the form action properly in the markup. Does it contain the tags asp-controller and asp-action?

Comment: @David Yes. It's one of possible problems - body couldn't be parsed as SignInViewModel, so, no matches in the controller are exist.

Comment: @CBreeze Could you also add description of SignInViewModel class?

Comment: @Dmitriy Sure, I've edited my question.

Comment: @Phiter Underneath the attributes section there is a section named `1: asp-action` but no section for the `asp-controller`

Comment: Attributes section? Weird, what browser is this? You should be seeing the simple markup as in HTML. Like `<form action="" method="post">`

Comment: @CBreeze So, firstly, without routes your SignIn controller will work with any post requests. Secondary, try to add SignIn() and look Request. (Form, Body, etc) property in this method body. It will give you an answer, probably...  Route("Auth") maybe?

Comment: @Phiter I've edited my answer to show the section I was looking at. The actual HTML looks fine.

Comment: @CBreeze replace that with a screenshot of the form in the "Elements" tab.

Comment: @Phiter editied to show the elements tab

Comment: Check this link  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38571762/how-to-call-this-post-action-method-using-ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I've made a new project in an attempt to replicate the issue and it works perfectly for me.
I'm assuming you're not using Areas also? If you are using areas, add this attribute to your controller class:

```
[Route("AreaNameHere")]
```

Although if you are able to get to the index page then this isn't the issue.

Are your breakpoints valid? Are symbols being loaded? It could be refreshing due to the ModelState being invalid or the details being invalid and so it's returning the same view. You could use fiddler to see if it's actually making a request at all.

EDIT:
Do you have this line "@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers" in your _ViewImports.cshtml file?

Comment: From the developer tools in Chrome it would seem like the asp-action isn't tied up to the form at all some how. Very confused for now...

Comment: Do you have this line

    "@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers"

 in your _ViewImports.cshtml file?

Comment: that was the issue if you would like to ask that as a question.

Comment: There you go, I've added it to the answer :)